# How to import a trained SVM detector in OpenCV 2.4.13

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, svm

So I have followed this guide to train my own pedestrian HOG detector. https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG/wiki/trainHOG-Tutorial

And it was successful with 4 files generated.

- cvHOGClassifier.yaml
- descriptorvector.dat
- features.dat
- svmlightmodel.dat

Does anyone know how to load the descriptorvector.dat file as a vector?
I've tried this but failed.

```
    vector<float> detector;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("descriptorvector.dat");
    file >> detector;
    file.close();
```

This is something I would like to use eventually.

```
    gpu::HOGDescriptor hog(Size(64, 128), Size(16, 16), Size(8, 8), Size(8, 8),9);
    hog.setSVMDetector(detector);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have already trained your SVM, you could just save the weights and the intercept in a TXT file and then load it in an array/vector. You would then use it as follows:

```
std::vector<float> descriptorsValues;   //A vector to store the computed HoG values
std::vector<cv::Point> locations;
hog.compute(image, descriptorsValues, cv::Size(0, 0), cv::Size(0, 0), locations);
double res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < svmDimension - 1; i++)
{
    res += w[i] * descriptorsValues.at(i);
}
res = res + w[svmDimension - 1];            
return res;
```

where `svmDimension` is the array/vector which contains the SVM weights followed by the SVM intercept, and `res` is the SVM response

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and push every value back to an array of `float`, so first declare it:

```
vector<float> myDescriptorVector;
```

Then push every value:

```
ifstream infile ("yourFile.dat".c_str());

float number;

while (infile >> number)
    myDescriptorVector.push_back(number);


return myDescriptorVector;
```

Finally use the standard initialization for the HOG and pass the vector to the SVM detector as you already guessed:

```
hog.setSVMDetector(myDescriptorVector);
```